# Determine remote and branch/tag from commit hash in Git

Tags: git

I have a repo with many different remotes where I've checked out a remote branch - `git checkout remote/branch`. I can get the currently checked out commit hash via `cat .git/HEAD` (since I'm always in a detached head state), but is there any way to figure out what remote and branch (or tag) that commit hash corresponds to?

Comment: `git branch -rv --abbrev=40|grep $(git rev-parse HEAD)` if you want to check just the remote branches' tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `git log -1 --decorate`.

This will show the current commit and which refs point to it.

You could also use `git branch -r --contains HEAD`, which will list all remote branches that contain the current commit.

Comment: The `git log...` command turns out to have more  of the information that I want; between the two of them I can get a complete picture of what's going on: If the commit is a branch head or a tag, the `git branch...` command doesn't say that, but the `git log...` command does. However, if the commit is just a hash, then `git log...` doesn't tell me the branch it's for, but `git branch` will.

Answer (score 2):

Given a commit hash, you can run `git branch -r --contains $COMMIT_HASH` to get all the remote branches that contain that commit.

Answer (score 1):

`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`

It will return the **just the name and nothing else**, of any remote/branch (local or remote) that has your current HEAD **at its tip**.

The [`git-rev-parse`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-parse.html) command, returns just the SHA1 for the reference passed. Using --abbrev-ref tells the command to return instead names for that reference.